# Variable of Radiobutton in tkinter Python not working

Tags: python, tkinter

On this code I'm trying to get working a Settings program, in which you can disable or enable the log. This code renders a Window, with a Settings button, when you press that button, it opens a new window with two Radio Button's (Enable/Disable), and the program should determine the current status of the setting, but I can't get it to work, because the variable (X) determines what option should be selected by default, according to the current status, but it doesn't work. Please help me!.

```
from msilib.schema import RadioButton
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as asset1
import tkinter 


settings = {"overrideAdminReq" : True}  # DEFAULT SETTING.

def showLogSettingToFalse(): # WHEN DISABLE BUTTON IS PRESSED.
    settings["overrideAdminReq"] = False # SET SETTING TO FALSE.
    print("Log was disabled")
def showLogSettingToTrue(): # WHEN ENABLE BUTTON IS PRESSED.
    settings["overrideAdminReq"] = True # SET SETTING TO TRUE.
    print("Log was enabled")

def showSettings(asset1): # WHEN SETTINGS BUTTON IS PRESSED.
    settingsWindow = Tk() # NEW WINDOW
    settingsWindow.title("Settings")
    settingsWindowGrid = asset1.Frame(settingsWindow, padx=2)
    settingsWindowGrid.pack()

    x = IntVar() # DEFINES THE VARIABLE
    if settings["overrideAdminReq"] == True: y=1 # IF SETTING IS TRUE, DEFINES Y = 1
    else: y=2 # IF SETTING IS FALSE, DEFINES Y = 2
    x.set(value=y) # SETS THE VALUE OF X WITH Y
    print("Log status: "+str(settings["overrideAdminReq"]))
    Label(settingsWindowGrid, text="Log Functionality:").grid(row=1,column=0) # TITLE LABEL.

    enableFunct = Radiobutton(settingsWindowGrid, # ENABLE OPTION.
        text="Enable",
        value=1, # OPTION VALUE
        variable=x,
        command=lambda: showLogSettingToTrue())
    enableFunct.grid(row=1,column=1)

    disableFunct = Radiobutton(settingsWindowGrid, # DISABLE OPTION.
        text="Disable",
        value=2, #OPTIONE VALUE
        variable=x, #VARIABLE
        command=lambda: showLogSettingToFalse())
    disableFunct.grid(row=2,column=1)

    settingsWindow.mainloop()

w1 = Tk()
button_1 = tkinter.Button(w1, text='Settings', padx=30, pady=5, command=lambda: showSettings(asset1), borderwidth=5)
button_1.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=2)
w1.mainloop()
```

Comment: P.D.: You can see on the CMD the current state of the log when you click Settings, and it's enabled by default, but the Radio buttons aren't marked correctly...

Comment: It is because you have two instances of `Tk()`.  Use `Toplevel()` inside `showSettings()`.  Normally `Toplevel` is used for child windows.  Also `mainloop()` should be called only once.  So remove `settingsWindow.mainloop()`.

Comment: @acw1668 In `settingsWindow = Tk()` I should replace `Tk()` with `Toplevel()`?

Comment: Yes, use `settingsWindow = Toplevel()`.

Comment: @acw1668 I replaced it, and i removed `settingsWindow.mainloop()` and the only difference is when i click "Settings", both Radio Buttons are empty... What I should do now?... Thank you for the help

Comment: It is because `x` is garbage collected.  Add `settingsWindow.var = x` at the end of `showSettings()` to keep a reference of `x`.